# is g++ reliant on Linux for running linux-like commands or are they built in?

Tags: makefile, g++

At the end of a makefile's execution there can be a `rm -rf *.o` inserted. Some of the variables such as $(something) seem very bash-like.

I had intended to create a makefile that compiles also on windows, but I am wondering this:

Is g++ relying on the linux environment for these commands or are they built in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

g++ is just a compiler and does not use makefiles. That is the role of the `make` tool (part of GNU autotools). You are expected to run `make` under a unix or unix-like environment (posix). In the case of windows compilation you can often use cygwin or msys to provide a unix-like environment with tools like `sh` and `rm`. [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com) is basically an emulator and includes the necessary tools and an emulation layer via a DLL. [MSYS](http://mingw.org/wiki/msys) is a suite of linux tools compiled to run under DOS/Windows enviroments and includes a shell.

Newer build systems like [CMake](https://cmake.org/) are preferable for cross-platform compiling as they can help you deal with OS abstraction and exceptions.

Comment: It is not true that `make` must be run in a unix or unix-like environment.  In addition to being built with cygwin or msys, GNU make (at least) can be built with straightforward Visual Studio as a standard Windows program without any special POSIX environment.  The `rm` you refer to is just something `make` prints out, but it's not actually running the `rm` program (if you are referring to deleting intermediate targets).  Beyond that, if you write your makefile recipes to use command.com as the shell instead of a UNIX shell you don't need any UNIX tools to use `make`.

Comment: Also just to be clear, cmake is not a build system.  cmake is a "meta" build system; that is, it's a system that can generate the input files for other build systems.  cmake itself cannot build your software, but it _can_, from a single (correctly written) cmake input file, generate control files for all different kinds of build systems: makefiles, but also Visual Studio Project files, Xcode project files, Eclipse project files, Ninja files, etc.